# Async.upload.php (Error Message: Failed to load response data)

Tags: uploads, login

I cannot upload an image using the media upload button as I receive this error `an error occurred in the upload. Please try again later` This will happen only if I login via the custom login page. But everything is normal if I login via `wp-login.php` I've disabled all the plugins, except for the custom login plugin because I have to login via this custom login page. And I've also switched back to the wp default theme. However, I still get this error. I've pressed F12 and been to the network tab in Chrome and I'v found that in the `Async.upload.php`, there's a message `Failed to load response data` on the right hand side as you can see in the picture. No other JS errors or other errors from the Chrome inspection, just this error. In addition, I've installed a plugin to detect any errors in WordPress but no errors found.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible you're mixing https and http? If you log in on one, sometimes you can't get to the other.

Comment: I'm working locally, using Wamp. Is it possible for that to happen?

Comment: Any time your domains don't match you can have issues. For example if you use an IP address one way (default WP-login) and "localhost" the other way (custom login page) that could explain the problem.

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: Visit your Core login page and visit your custom login page. Compare domains and determine whether they're using http or https. Verify they're both using the same.

Comment: Sorry, I'm newbie. This is what you mean? I've been to wp-login.php and this is what displayed in the file: // Redirect to https login if forced to use SSL
if ( force_ssl_admin() && ! is_ssl() ) {
 if ( 0 === strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http') ) {
  wp_redirect( set_url_scheme( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'https' ) );
  exit();
 } else {
  wp_redirect( 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
  exit();
 }
}

Comment: And this what displayed in the plugin file: ///setting the paths
if (!defined('IHC_PATH')){
 define('IHC_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
}
if (!defined('IHC_URL')){
 define('IHC_URL', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__));
}
if (!defined('IHC_PROTOCOL')){
 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'){
  define('IHC_PROTOCOL', 'https://');
 } else {
  define('IHC_PROTOCOL', 'http://'); 
 }
}

Comment: Not the contents of the files. When you actually visit them in a browser, compare the URLs.

Comment: I've copied the URLs and paste them in notepad. Both are same. http://. I've removed the custom login plugin and installed it again. The result is same. Also deactivated all the plugins and switched to the default theme. It's same. Nothing changed. Why?

Comment: I would contact the plugin author. It's pretty clear their login plugin is causing the issue (or conflicting) in some way.